# labor supply model

Tags: labor-economics

Consider a concave utility function $u(c, l)$ where $c$ represents **consumption** good and $l$
represents **labour supply** (working hours, to be precise). While utility increases as level of consumption good, increasing working hours reduces utility. Wage per hour
of labour is given by $w$, thus working for $l$ hours will ensure $wl$ amount of total wage
which is denoted by y, that is, $y = wl$ g for l hours will ensure $wl$ amount of total wage
which is denoted by y, that is, $y = wl$. Given this, the utility function can be written as $u(c, y/w)$
The price of the consumption good $c$ is given by $p$. Also $L^¯$ is a fixed number of
hours representing total time available to an agent and $L^¯ − l$ represents leisure.

Assuming y on x-axis and c on y- axis.  Derive the slope of an indifference curve for the utility function $u(c,y/w)$.
Show the agent’s utility maximizing choice of $y$ and $c$ in a figure by plotting
her budget line and indifference curves for the utility function $u(c,y/w)$.

As the *Marginal utility* from $c$ is positive and that of $l$ is negative so we can find the slope of the  *IC* by calculating the MRS, my **answer** is coming out to be $-1/pw$ for the slope of the *IC* but i'm affraid that is giving me the optimal point and not the slope.
can someone please explain?
thank you

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain how you get this $-p$?

Comment: $p$ is not a variable of $u(.)$, so it's irrelevant; you seem to have done a constrained optimisation, which is being asked later. The last lines of both first and second paragraph are not relevant to deriving IC.

IC will be derived the usual way, using implicit differentiation except with the twist that you are to find the slope with respect to a function of the input $y$ and not the input itself $l=y/w$, which you can get around using chain rule. If you don't know what I am talking, you are not ready for this question and should go back to the theory.

Comment: @Giskard i'm so sorry, when i was solving i normalised w to 1 yet it is still wrong. it should be $-1/pw$.

Comment: @ShaikhAmmar I am aware of the fact that $p$ and $w$ are not variables in the *work-leisure problem* but rather a fixed parameter. i just am trying to create a picture of the graph of $u(c,y/w)$. and i may not be ready for this question but i am still willing to try.